# Sending key with wmctrl

Tags: wmctrl

Is it possible using `wmctrl` to send keystrokes to a window? I know it's possible by using `xdotool`. Both tools are very similar, so maybe I missed something when I read the man pages for `wmctrl`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, `wmctrl` doesn't have ability to send keystrokes in the sense of typing out letters and key combinations. There is `-c` flag for closing window, which can be used to emulate <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> for closing a window, but that's a stretch of reasoning.

You can combine those, of course, although `wmctrl` refers to window XIDs in hexadecimal format,so you may have to make conversion between those. `xdotool` alone, however, is sufficient to send keystrokes to specific windows.